# why is this code confusing the user selection at one point of the execution, i really cant find the issue

Tags: javascript

So its a memory game, eventlisteners acknowledge user input after a sequence of divs change color simualting to be iluminated, the expected behavior is once the user clicks the right div in the right order the sequence starts over adding 1 more div to be illuminated until you get to the last number in the array and then a function lets you know you win or if you choose the wrong div at any point you trigger a function to let you know that you lose, after both cases the game starts again. now the problem is that at some point (and its kind of random that the werid thing, usuarlly between the 4 to 6 divs illuminated) even if you choose the right set of divs the function for losing gets trigger, and when you start over the game (without refreshing the page) the code triggers the function for losing in the first try the function destined to check and compare the user input is chooseColor(ev), and the variables destined keep track of the levels (level y sublvl) are set to restart everytime you win or lose,

```
> <script>
      const boton = document.getElementById("btnEmpezar");

      const verde = document.getElementById("verde");
      const amarillo = document.getElementById("amarillo");
      const azul = document.getElementById("azul");
      const rojo = document.getElementById("rojo");
      const blanco = document.getElementById("blanco");

      const box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
      const box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
      const box3 = document.getElementById("box3");
      const box4 = document.getElementById("box4");

      const loser = document.getElementById("loser");
      const winner = document.getElementById("winner");

      let level = 0;
      const last_Lvl = 10;
      let sublvl = 0;
      const colores = {
        verde,
        amarillo,
        azul,
        rojo,
        blanco,
        box1,
        box2,
        box3,
        box4,
      };
      let timeoutIluminacion = null;

      let secuencia = new Array(10)
        .fill(0)
        .map((n) => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));

      function generarSecuencia() {
        secuencia = new Array(10)
          .fill(0)
          .map((n) => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));
        console.log(sublvl);
      }

      const nota1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
      const nota2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
      const nota3 = document.getElementById("audio3");
      const nota4 = document.getElementById("audio4");
      const nota5 = document.getElementById("audio5");
      const nota6 = document.getElementById("audio6");
      const nota7 = document.getElementById("audio7");
      const nota8 = document.getElementById("audio8");
      const nota9 = document.getElementById("audio9");

      function tocarNota(color) {
        switch (color) {
          case "rojo":
            return nota1.play();
          case "verde":
            return nota1.play();
          case "amarillo":
            return nota2.play();
          case "azul":
            return nota3.play();
          case "blanco":
            return nota5.play();
          case "box1":
            return nota6.play();
          case "box2":
            return nota7.play();
          case "box3":
            return nota8.play();
          case "box4":
            return nota9.play();
        }
      }

      function hideButton() {
        boton.classList.add("hide");

        setTimeout(enlightSequence, 500);
      }

      function enlightSequence() {
        for (let i = 0; i <= level; i++) {
          const color = transformarNumeroAColor(secuencia[i]);
          setTimeout(() => iluminarColor(color), 1400 * i);
          console.log(color);
        }
        agregarEventosClick();
      }

      function iluminarColor(color) {
        colores[color].classList.add("light");
        /*tocarNota(color)*/
        setTimeout(() => this.apagarColor(color), 350);
      }

      function apagarColor(color) {
        colores[color].classList.remove("light");
      }

      function transformarNumeroAColor(numero) {
        switch (numero) {
          case 0:
            return "rojo";
          case 1:
            return "verde";
          case 2:
            return "amarillo";
          case 3:
            return "azul";
          case 4:
            return "blanco";
          case 5:
            return "box1";
          case 6:
            return "box2";
          case 7:
            return "box3";
          case 8:
            return "box4";
        }
      }

      function transformarColorANumero(color) {
        switch (color) {
          case "rojo":
            return 0;
          case "verde":
            return 1;
          case "amarillo":
            return 2;
          case "azul":
            return 3;
          case "blanco":
            return 4;

          case "box1":
            return 5;
          case "box2":
            return 6;
          case "box3":
            return 7;
          case "box4":
            return 8;
        }
      }

      function agregarEventosClick() {
        colores.verde.addEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.amarillo.addEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.rojo.addEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.azul.addEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.blanco.addEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);

        colores.box1.addEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.box2.addEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.box3.addEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.box4.addEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
      }

      function eliminarEventosClick() {
        colores.verde.removeEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.amarillo.removeEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.rojo.removeEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.azul.removeEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.blanco.removeEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);

        colores.box1.removeEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.box2.removeEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.box3.removeEventListener("click", this.chooseColor);
        colores.box4.removeEventListener("click", this.choosecolor);
      }

      function chooseColor(ev) {
        const nombreColor = ev.target.dataset.color;
        const numeroColor = transformarColorANumero(nombreColor);
        iluminarColor(nombreColor);
        if (numeroColor === secuencia[sublvl]) {
          sublvl++;
          console.log(sublvl);
          if (sublvl > level) {
            eliminarEventosClick();
            level++;
            sublvl = 0;

            timeoutIluminacion = setTimeout(enlightSequence, 1500);
          }
          if (level === last_Lvl + 1) {
            eliminarEventosClick();
            setTimeout(secuenciaFinal, 700);
            clearTimeout(timeoutIluminacion);
          }
        } else {
          eliminarEventosClick();
          setTimeout(perdioJuego, 700);
        }
      }

      function ganoJuego() {
        winner.classList.remove("hide");

        setTimeout(start, 1000);
      }

      function start() {
        winner.classList.add("hide");
        boton.classList.remove("hide");
        level = 0;
        generarSecuencia();
      }

      function perdioJuego() {
        loser.classList.remove("hide");
        setTimeout(startos, 1000);
      }

      function startos() {
        loser.classList.add("hide");
        boton.classList.remove("hide");
        level = 0;
        sublvl = 0;
        generarSecuencia();
      }

      function secuenciaFinal() {
        eliminarEventosClick();
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          setTimeout(enlightSequenceFinal, 1000 * i);
        }

        setTimeout(ganoJuego, 4000);
      }

      function enlightSequenceFinal() {
        colores.amarillo.classList.add("light");
        colores.verde.classList.add("light");
        colores.rojo.classList.add("light");
        colores.azul.classList.add("light");

        setTimeout(TurnOffFinal, 500);
      }

      function TurnOffFinal() {
        colores.amarillo.classList.remove("light");
        colores.rojo.classList.remove("light");
        colores.verde.classList.remove("light");
        colores.azul.classList.remove("light");

        enlightSequenceFinal2();
      }

      function enlightSequenceFinal2() {
        colores.box1.classList.add("light");
        colores.box2.classList.add("light");
        colores.box3.classList.add("light");
        colores.box4.classList.add("light");
        setTimeout(TurnOffFinal2, 500);
      }

      function TurnOffFinal2() {
        colores.box1.classList.remove("light");
        colores.box2.classList.remove("light");
        colores.box3.classList.remove("light");
        colores.box4.classList.remove("light");
      }
    </script>



>  <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .gameboard {
        border: 2px solid black;
        width: 300px;
        height: 260px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background-color: black;
        border-radius: 5%;
        position: relative;
      }
      .polen {
        position: absolute;
        border: 3px solid black;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: blueviolet;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        top: calc(0% - 50px);
        left: calc(-20% - 200px);
        z-index: 2;
      }

      .box {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        z-index: 0;
        height: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0;
        border-radius: 5%;
      }
      .uno {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 223, 0.767);
        position: relative;
      }

      .uno.light {
        background-color: rgba(129, 129, 252, 0.767);
      }

      .dos {
        background-color: rgb(49, 122, 55);
      }
      .dos.light {
        background-color: rgb(102, 126, 104);
      }

      .tres {
        background-color: rgb(198, 209, 43);
        position: relative;
      }

      .tres.light {
        background-color: rgb(209, 212, 156);
      }

      .cuatro {
        background-color: rgb(177, 12, 12);
      }

      .cuatro.light {
        background-color: rgb(196, 111, 111);
      }

      .petado {
        width: 130px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 3px solid black;
        background-color: rgb(252, 255, 55);
        display: flex;
        align-self: flex-end;
        border-top-left-radius: 60%;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
        z-index: 1;
      }

      .petado.light {
        background-color: rgb(252, 253, 201);
      }

      .petado.dark {
        background-color: rgb(195, 197, 48);
      }

      .petaun {
        width: 130px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 3px solid black;
        display: flex;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
        border-top-right-radius: 60%;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
      }

      .petaun.light {
        background-color: rgb(255, 129, 129);
      }

      .petaun.dark {
        background-color: rgb(177, 0, 0);
      }

      .petatre {
        width: 130px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 3px solid black;
        display: flex;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        background-color: rgb(79, 255, 88);
        border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
        border-top-left-radius: 50%;
      }

      .petatre.light {
        background-color: rgb(215, 253, 217);
      }

      .petatre.dark {
        background-color: rgb(65, 190, 71);
      }

      .petacua {
        width: 130px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 3px solid black;
        display: flex;
        background-color: blue;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 60%;
        border-top-right-radius: 50%;
      }

      .petacua.light {
        background-color: rgb(138, 138, 255);
      }

      .petacua.dark {
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 211);
      }

      .polen {
        position: absolute;
        border: 10px solid black;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        top: calc(50% - 33px);

        left: calc(50% - 33px);
      }

      .polen.light {
        background-color: rgb(133, 127, 127);
      }

      .polen.dark {
        background-color: rgb(207, 205, 205);
      }

      .boton {
        position: absolute;
        border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
        color: aliceblue;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: rgb(27, 26, 26);
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        top: calc(50% - 31px);

        left: calc(50% - 30px);
        z-index: 4;
        font-size: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .boton.hide {
        display: none;
      }

      .boton:hover {
        border: 0.01px solid rgb(10, 10, 10);

        color: black;

        transition: 0.3s border ease-in 0.1s;
      }
      .boton:focus {
        outline: 0;
      }

      .resultado {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
        border-radius: 5%;
        color: white;
        font-size: 55px;
        background-color: black;
        font-family: monospace;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
      }

      .resultados {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
        border-radius: 5%;
        color: white;
        font-size: 55px;
        background-color: black;
        font-family: monospace;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
      }

      .resultado.hide {
        display: none;
      }

      .resultados.hide {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="gameboard">
      <div class="box uno" id="box1" data-color="box1">
        <div id="rojo" class="petaun" data-color="rojo"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box dos" id="box2" data-color="box2">
        <div id="amarillo" class="petado" data-color="amarillo"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box tres" id="box3" data-color="box3">
        <div id="verde" class="petatre" data-color="verde"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box cuatro" id="box4" data-color="box4">
        <div id="azul" class="petacua" data-color="azul"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="blanco" class="polen" data-color="blanco"></div>
      <button id="btnEmpezar" class="boton" onclick="hideButton()">
        Start!
      </button>

      <div id="winner" class="resultado hide">
        <p>
          You <br />
          Win! :)
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="loser" class="resultados hide">
        <p>
          :( <br />
          You lose!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <audio src="./notas/nota1.mp3" id="audio1" preload="metadata"></audio>
    <audio src="./notas/nota2.mp3" id="audio2" preload="metadata"></audio>
    <audio src="./notas/nota3.mp3" id="audio3" preload="metadata"></audio>
    <audio src="./notas/nota4.mp3" id="audio4" preload="metadata"></audio>

    <audio src="./notas/nota5.mp3" id="audio5" preload="metadata"></audio>
    <audio src="./notas/nota6.mp3" id="audio6" preload="metadata"></audio>
    <audio src="./notas/nota7.mp3" id="audio7" preload="metadata"></audio>
    <audio src="./notas/nota8.mp3" id="audio8" preload="metadata"></audio>
    <audio src="./notas/nota9.mp3" id="audio9" preload="metadata"></audio>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do we need all 558 lines of code, including the audio, all the CSS, and the different colors to reproduce the problem? Please [edit] your post and replace your code by a [mre]. Sounds like the game is restarting with some previous state. Well, you’re using global variables instead of scoping everything, so you’d have to manually reset every single one of them. This is prone to error.

Comment: Would be helpful to simplify/rephrase your explanation and clearly define the problem - it's hard to follow one long run-on sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, as far as I can see with my rusty Spanish, losing a game means calling the function `perdioJuego`.

I don't know where it goes wrong exactly, but I'm 100% sure that your problem is to find when monitoring the `else`-twig of your `chooseColor()` function. There must be some situation when the system gets into the `else` part unexpectedly. Have a look at the 3 values then as shown below.

```
      function chooseColor(ev) {
        const nombreColor = ev.target.dataset.color;
        const numeroColor = transformarColorANumero(nombreColor);
        iluminarColor(nombreColor);
        if (numeroColor === secuencia[sublvl]) {

          // the rest of your code

        } else {

          // check here
          console.log("sublvl: " + sublvl);
          console.log("numeroColor: " + numeroColor);
          console.log("secuencia[sublvl]: " + secuencia[sublvl]);

          eliminarEventosClick();
          setTimeout(perdioJuego, 700);
        }
      }
```